# Finding ID from related model Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, laravel-8

I am working with three models:

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'group'
    ];
...

    public function permission()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
    }
}
```

Profile Model

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'profiles';
    protected $fillable = [
        'profile_name',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'profile_type',
        'TFN',
        'ABN',
        'ACN',
        'Address',
        'Email',
        'Phone',
        'established_date',
        'Notes',
        'activated'
    ];

   ...

    public function permission()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
    }

}
```

Permission Model

```
class Permission extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'permissions';
    protected $fillable = [
        'profile_id',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

Any user can have access to 0 or many profiles
Any profile can have permission given to 0 or many users

On the users.edit blade template I am creating toggle buttons to add/remove profile permissions for the selected user, using the permissions.store and permissions.destroy routes. Creating a new permission is working as expected, however I am having trouble accessing the permission id (marked **** in blade snippet) in order to trigger the destroy function.

User Controller

```
 public function edit(User $user, Profile $profile, Permission $permission)
    {    
        
        $perm = Permission::where([
            ['user_id', '=', $user->id],
        ])->pluck('profile_id', 'id')->toArray();
               
        return view('users.edit', compact('perm'))
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('profiles', Profile::all());

    }
```

Permission Controller

```
public function destroy(Permission $permission, User $user, Profile $profile)
    {      
        $permission = Permission::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
        ->where('profile_id', '=', $profile->id)
        ->firstOrFail();

        $permission->delete();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Blade snippet

```
 @foreach($profiles as $key => $profile)
            
              @if(in_array($profile->id, $perm))
              <form action="{{ route('permissions.destroy', **** ) }}" method="POST" >
                     @csrf 
                     @method('DELETE')
                     <input type="hidden" value="{{ $user->id }}" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
                     <input type="hidden" value="{{ $profile->id }}" name="profile_id" id="profile_id" />
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{{ $profile->profile_name }}</button>
                  </form>
              
              @else
               <form action="{{ route('permissions.store') }}" method="POST" >
                     @csrf 
                     <input type="hidden" value="{{ $user->id }}" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
                     <input type="hidden" value="{{ $profile->id }}" name="profile_id" id="profile_id" />
                     <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">{{ $profile->profile_name }}</button>
                  </form>
               @endif

                           @endforeach
```

Thanks in advance

The permission ID is included in the array $perm created in the User controller, but I haven't found a way to call that value and associate it with the permission record so that I can send it to the permission.destroy route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the permission ID as a parameter to the route in the action attribute of the form.

To do this, try replacing **** with `['permission' => array_search($profile->id, $perm)]`.

Here, the array_search() function is used to find the index of the profile ID in the $perm array, and the corresponding permission ID is accessed using that index. This value is then passed as a parameter named permission to the route in the form's action attribute.

Comment: The $perm array looks like this:
`Array ( [13] => 2 [14] => 3 [15] => 4 ) 1`

Using `['permission' => $perm[array_search($profile->id, $perm)]]` returns the 2, 3 or 4
I need to access the 13, 14, or 15

Comment: I changed it to: 

`['permission' => array_search($profile->id, $perm)]` and it worked!

Thank you for your help and very descriptive answer!

Comment: You're welcome :D! I'm glad you found something that worked for you :). I've updated my answer to include your solution. If your happy with the answer please upvote+accept it (you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside my answer, accepting an answer gives you +2reputation).